# Call AlertDialog from another class

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I have decided to place all dialogs in a Notify class.

However when i attempt to call a dialog, the application crashes

This is the Notify class:

```
public class Notify extends Activity
{


public void  errorHandler(String title, Exception e)
{
    eH(title, e);
}

public void  messageBox(String title, String details)
{
    alertDialog(title, details);
}

    //***************************************************************
//display error dialog.
//****************************************************************
private void eH(String method, Exception e)
{
    Log.e("FIRSTDROID EXCEPTION", method + " : " + e.getMessage());

    e.printStackTrace();

    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle(method);
    alertDialog.setMessage(e.getMessage());
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.quiticon);
    alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    alertDialog.show();
}


//*************************************************************
//generic dialog for messages to the user
//*************************************************************
private void alertDialog(String title, String message)
{       
    Log.i("Message", message);

    AlertDialog.Builder messageBox;
    messageBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(null);
    messageBox.setTitle(title);
    messageBox.setMessage(message);
    messageBox.setIcon(R.drawable.infoicon);
    messageBox.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
    messageBox.setCancelable(false);
    messageBox.show();
}
```

I create a new instance of Notify, and call messageBox, like so:

```
Notify notify = new Notify();

notify.messageBox("Test Title", "Test Message");
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

android.app.AlertDialog.Builder.Builder(Context context), so u need transfer this or ApplicationContext just like eH() method,

alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

for another, why do u create one activity and call its public method? what's the meaning, I hava no idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

You forget **.create()** in your alertDialog method while you are initializing the messageBox variable. This might lead to crash in your application.
And you should pass the Context in **AlertDialog.Builder** like **messageBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());** or **messageBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);**

Comment: I have tried passing through the context as well as: messageBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext()).create(); but i still gt the crash

Comment: @LouisEvans : Did you define Notify class in your manifest file as a activity? Just checking because sometime many forget to add the activity in manifest file.

Comment: @LouisEvans [This link](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-alert-dialog-example/) might solve your problem. I forgot the order in which alertDialog and DialogBuilder define. Hope this will work for you.

Comment: thanks for that, but it still wont work. I must be missing something really obvious

Comment: yeah, may be it can be possible.Last try from myside...TRY THIS `AlertDialog.Builder messageBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);<br> messageBox.setTitle(title); messageBox.setMessage(message); messageBox.setIcon(R.drawable.infoicon); messageBox.setNeutralButton("OK", null); messageBox.setCancelable(false); AlertDialog alertDialog = messageBox.create(); alertDialog.show();`